# Why Longest common string can not recursive first and output latter

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Here i want to output the longest common string using dynamic programming algorithm ,code below is my implementation.what make me wired is the output `A  C  A  D  C  B`, it's obviously wrong, and if i change these two lines and make it print first and recurse latter, result is true.and i have draw such process in paper and really do not know why the first is wrong.

`display(flags, c, x-1, y-1);
System.out.print(c[x] + "  ");`:

```
    public class LCSubstring{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] x = {"", "A","B","A","D","F","E","C","A"};
        String[] y = {"", "B","A","C","A","D","F","C","B","A"};
        int[][] flags = getFlag(x, y);
        display(flags, x, x.length-1, y.length-1);
    }
    public static int[][] getFlag(String[] x, String[] y){
        int[][] c = new int[x.length][y.length];
        int[][] b = new int[x.length][y.length];
        for(int i = 1; i < x.length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < y.length; j++){
                if(x[i] == y[j]){

                    c[i][j] = c[i-1][j-1] + 1;
                    b[i][j] = 1;
                }else if(c[i][j-1] >= c[i-1][j]){

                    c[i][j] = c[i][j-1];
                    b[i][j] = 0;
                }else{

                    c[i][j] = c[i-1][j];
                    b[i][j] = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
    public static void display(int[][] flags, String[] c, int x, int y){

        if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
            return;
        }
        if(flags[x][y] == 1){

            display(flags, c, x-1, y-1);
            System.out.print(c[x] + "  ");
        }else if(flags[x][y] == 0){
            display(flags, c, x, y-1);
        }else if(flags[x][y] == -1){
            display(flags, c, x-1, y);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:non-recursive in finding result**

```
public static void display(int[][] flags, String[] c, int x, int y){
    while (x != 0 && y != 0){
        if (flags[x][y] == 1){
            System.out.print(c[x] + " ");
            x--;
            y--;
        }else if (flags[x][y] == 0){
            y--;
        }else if (flags[x][y] == -1){
            x--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: if memory serves correctly, then dynamic-programming builds the solution gradually instead of top-to-bottom (hence it is typically iterative rather than recursive, which is kind of in contrast with your description).

Comment: @barakmanos so you means the first kind recursive solution is false although reverse the two line? and i have update the non-recursive implementation.but i wonder some textbook ever said every recursive implementation can be realized using non-recursive but recursive usage can make your program more comprehensive.so i don't think dynamic-programming solutions can not use recurse.And i really appreciate if you can give more detail about my post error.

Comment: You can use recursive solutions with dynamic-programming. Although you may need to used techniques like `memoization` to get optimal performance. [Info on dynamic programming, recursion and memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

Answer (score 0):

When traversing trees (which your code is effectively doing), you can traverse in one of three *orders*:

- pre-order
- in-order
- post-order

Reference [Tree traversal on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

When you change the order of the 2 lines in your code, you are switching between *pre-order* and *in-order* traversal. Take a look at the Wikipedia article and it should help you understand the difference between the different traversal orders, and how to code for them.